# analog BANDPASS filter difference equation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

does anyone know what is the difference equation for band pass filters in terms of bandwidth,low frequency,high frequency....
I'm trying to design a band pass DISCRETE filter using Mat lab !

Comment: For the first part of a question you may take a look at http://www.sp4comm.org/webversion.html . This will give you an understanding of difference equations and this'll be enough to understand the corresponding MATLAB help entry.